# DLL injection - calling a procedure of a target process

Tags: dll, call, code-injection, procedure

I am learning about DLL injection, now, i have successfully injected my dll, (i have checked it by adding `while(1){}` to it) and i would like to call internal functions of my target process (in example executing an internal function of the process, that writes something on the screen). I am not sure how all of this works, can anyone point me to some well described tutorials / manuals? It's hard to find this info by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Jeffrey Richter's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735663777) book. I just love it. There is entire looong chapter about DLL injecting an API hooking. I guess this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You must also take a look at ["Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces) ! Robert Kuster has written an excellent article on some very intelligent injection mechanisms, not described in Jeffrey Richter's Book. It works pretty well.